# Extending Fagin's Theorem to the Polynomial Hierarchy

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, logic, np, first-order-logic

Fagin's Theorem (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fagin%27s_theorem) and [these lecture notes](https://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/%7Eu5170295/pdf/fmt3-4.pdf)) states that there is an equivalence between second-order logic (SOL) formulas with existential quantifiers, and problems in NP.

**I was wondering if we can also extend this result to other complexity classes in the polynomial hierarchy?**

For example, can we state that deciding any SOL formula of the following form $\exists \forall \phi $ is in the ${‎‎\sum^{P}_2}$ (a.k.a., [S2P](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S2P_(complexity))) complexity class? Recall that S2P is the complexity class of all problems which we can solve in NP, given that we can solve co-NP problems in constant time (e.g., $\exists x_1, \ldots, x_n\forall y_1, \ldots, y_m \space \psi$, for a 3-SAT formula $\psi$).

It inductively seems to be possible to extend Fagin's theorem for these cases but would appreciate any feedback.

Thanks very much!

Comment: $S_2^P$ is a different (smaller) class than $\Sigma_2^P$. But otherwise, yes: $\Sigma_k^P$ coincides with languages with languages definable by $\exists_k$ SO sentences (i.e., with $k$ alternating blocks of SO quantifiers, starting with an existential block, followed by an FO formula).

Comment: Thanks very much Emil!
Also, is it possible to briefly emphasize the difference between Sigma_{2}^{P} and S2P? In what sense is S2pP ``smaller''?

Thanks very much again!

Comment: See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/S2P_(complexity)#Relationship_to_other_complexity_classes